# Gatling not honouring -bdf parameter

Tags: gatling

I am doing a `post(someUrl).body(RawFileBody("100_msg.json")).asJSON`.
However I keep getting an error `file 100_msgs.json   doesn't exist`.

I am passing a `-bdf` parameter that is pointing to a folder that contains the said json, but the same result. (At some point, I definitely saw something work, but not anymore)

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and configured a gradle to invoke Gatling. Am new to Scala, so debugging this seems a herculean task. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Oops my bad. I had a space in the file name.